# Advertising on other SE sites

Tags: discussion

All, I saw this message on Gardening.SE. They were wanting me to resize an image I was working on for them.  There are other SE's out there which will advertise for us, if we post up an image for them to display. For instance, here is one for [Cooking.SE](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/community-promotion-ads-2016)

I came up with a speedy type PS chop job with this image:

[image]

I know this is basic and may work, but wondering what everyone else thinks. You may even want to come up with your own design. There are some parameters you have to meet for the design, though ...

## Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if
  retina (600x500).
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 40 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, **there
  must be a 1px border surrounding it**.

Please give me your thoughts as to what you might want to see or post up your own images ... I'd like to see what we can come up with.

Comment: @BobCross  ... can we add the [tag:community-ads] tag to this? Can only be used by a moderator.

Comment: Well, I have to say, I was shot down in a blaze of glory at the two sites I tried to add community ads to. I'll keep looking, but I think in the cross-over realm, there isn't much here on SE for MVM&R to cross-over to.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another chop which I posted over on Cooking.SE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something that:

- even a casual SE user who knows nothing about cars can identify as a "car-related thing"
- makes use of the space available
- looks good on a white page

Here are some images that I think most people who own a vehicle would understand. The Mechanics.SE logo would have to be positioned somewhere in the image as well then.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I'm adding this one after a simple Paint hack job on it. I believe this is something along the lines of what Zaid is looking for:

[image]